# How Can I Discover Former Moderators?

Tags: discussion, moderation, election

After many years of helping our site, especially through extensive edits and brilliant responses, @mbq and @cardinal have been promoted to moderators emeriti.

Although the diamonds no longer appear next to their names, I hope they will continue to participate when they can. They will always be welcome and their voices will for ever carry great weight for me and, I am sure, for many others.  Please join me in congratulating and thanking them for their service.

In the future, though, how can visitors who were not with this site all along discover who the moderators have been?

#### Postscript

After this eulogy was posted, @cardinal requested the opportunity to return to the trenches and has re-acquired the moderator diamond.  Welcome back, Cardinal, as our first resurrected (*zombie?*) moderator!

Comment: Thanks for this post, and all my best wishes to @mbq and @cardinal! I hope I will have the opportunity to learn more from them. This was really a rewarding adventure. Congrats to you, guys, and this particular promotion, whuber! Cheers

Answer (score 17, accepted):

An historical record of all elections to date is maintained at https://stats.stackexchange.com/election.  There you can find summaries and links to the original election pages (which provide details right down to the voting records).

The [Sheriff Badge](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/badges/128/sheriff) is awarded to anyone who has served as an elected moderator for at least a year.  By linking to the list of awardees, you can see who has served as moderator and (by subtracting one year) deduce when they were elected.

The [Constable Badge](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/badges/127/constable) was uniquely awarded to the original moderators who shepherded this site through its beta stage into into being.

By searching this (meta) site for ["Election"](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=election) you can find records of our elections, including who ran and the [outcomes.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=election%20results)

Comment: There's also a page that summarizes election results on the main site: http://stats.stackexchange.com/election

Comment: @Shog9 Thank you for that: I have incorporated your information as the lead to this answer.